Как сделать отображение информации о заказах, только пренадлежавших текущему пользователю?
Есть база данных flask-sqlachemy с определенным заказом. В ней есть столбец с id пользователя, совершивший этот самый заказ. Как сделать так, чтобы на странице отображались только те заказы, которые принадлежат текущему пользователю? Его айди должен совпадать с айди пользователя, который сделал заказ. В моем коде отображаются все заказы.
PYTHON
@app.route('/yourtrades', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def yourtrades():
    trade = Trade.query.order_by(Trade.trade_date.desc()).all()

return render_template('cabinet/yourtrades.html', trade=trade)

HTML
<div class="bd_box_of_goods">

    {% if trade %}
        {% for el in trade %}
        <div class="goods">
            <p>ID заказа -<strong>{{ el.trade_id }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>ID продукта -<strong>{{ el.trade_prod_id }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>Название продукта -<strong>{{ el.trade_prod_name }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>Цена продукта -<strong>{{ el.trade_prod_price }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>Размер продукта -<strong>{{ el.trade_prod_size }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>ID пользователя -<strong>{{ el.trade_user_id }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>Почта пользователя -<strong>{{ el.trade_user_email }}</strong>-</p>
            <p>Дата создания -<strong>{{ el.trade_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S') }}</strong>-</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <div class="goods goodscenter">
            <p>Текущих заказов пока нет :(</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

</div>


Ну так в trade = Trade.query.order_by(Trade.trade_date.desc()).all() вместо all() используйте filter().

Хорошо, а как сделать отображение? Синтаксис джинджи

Отображение будет такое же. данные в переменной trade поменяются на только.
